# Switching remote to a specific branch

Tags: git, branch

So I understand the value of branching, but one thing is confusing me. I have my local repo. I push changes to a remote, which has a post receive hook set up to write files on a website. So I create a branch (new-branch) to try out something. I edit files, commit, and push to the remote. Great. Problem is, while the repo on my remote is up to date, I guess it's still set to master, as the changes in new-branch aren't reflected on the site. How do I set the remote to a particular branch so that branch is driving the post receive hook, and not just defaulting to the master branch? I would just merge on master but I'm not ready to as I'm still working out the kinks on the branch.

Comment: Are you asking how you get the remote to deploy some other branch(es) automatically, even though they're already automatically deploying updates that go to `master`?  What do you want them to do with pushes to `master` in the meantime?

Comment: I want to determine which branch is deployed, yes. Changes in master will still be in the repo. This is so I can test a branch on a server as I develop, before committing to master. When I change branches on local, all my working files are update to match the active branch. I just assumed this could be done to a remote too. Still new to git. :)

Comment: BTW, the answer is now about "deploying multiple branches", which might be a better subject line for the question, if that's really what you were asking.  (I hope it was :-) )

Answer (score 3):

OK, based on comments, it sounds like you control the server too, which is needed here.  (That is, where I write "they" below, it's just you yourself, but wearing a different hat, as it were.)

#### Let's start with some background: `git push` and "bare" repositories

From git's point of view, you work on your repo, and they (whoever they are) work on their repo.  So when you do a `git push`, which delivers commits you've made directly to their repo, they're probably working on their repo.  They probably have some branch checked out and are in the middle of editing *their* copy of `xyz.html` or whatever.

If your push overwrote their `xyz.html`, wouldn't that annoy them?  They're in the middle of editing!  So, for a conventional repository, git will reject an attempt to push to whatever branch is currently checked-out (the one `git status` prints as "# on branch ...", or shown by `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD`).<sup>1</sup>  You can only push to *other* branches, which by definition, they're not working on, so they won't get annoyed.

Now, in fact, a lot of these centralized "push here" repositories *don't* have anyone working on them.  They're often set up as "bare" repositories, which means they have no work-tree at all.  This in turn means the "they"—whoever "they" may be—cannot possibly be working on their copy of `xyz.html`, since they don't *have* a working copy of `xyz.html` in the first place.  Cloning with `--bare`, or converting a regular repository to a bare one, disables the "can't push to current branch" check, which is what they want here.

---

<sup>1</sup>In particular, you get a "refusing to update checked out branch" error.  This is actually configurable, via `receive.denyCurrentBranch`, in the (non-bare) repository on the server.

---

#### Auto-deploy

So far so good; but now they may want their central push-server bare repo to *also* automatically deploy to a web site (or, for code repositories, to a test system like Jenkins, or whatever)—the key point is that "they", whoever they are again, have a post-receive hook that deploys one particular branch.  But we just described the bare repository as having no work-tree.  How does this auto-deploy work?  Let's put on our other hat and become "them".

Because this is git, there are actually lots of ways, but the usual (and maybe-best) method is with a post-receive script that checks which branch(es) are being updated, and if the interesting one(s) is/are pushed-to, does the deployment.

Here's an example of a ridiculously simple `post-receive` hook shell script that has an unimplemented `deploy` shell function to deploy pushes to `master`:

```
#! /bin/sh

deploy()
{
    local newref=$1 branch=$2

    echo deploy invoked: $newref $branch
}

while read oldsha newsha refname; do
    case "$refname" in
    refs/heads/master) deploy $newsha ${refname#refs/heads/};;
    esac
done
```

Git runs the post-receive hook with its stdin being fed a series of input lines.  Each line has three items.  The last one is the full name of the reference, so branch master is `refs/heads/master`.  The first two are the "old" SHA-1 and the "new" SHA-1 respectively, for that reference.

At most one of the old and new SHA-1 values can be 40 `0` characters: this means the reference is being created (old-SHA-1 is all zeros) or deleted (new is all zeros).  Otherwise, the reference currently exists and is simply being updated (pointed to a new commit, normally): it used to point to the old ID and now points to the new.

(In a *pre*-receive hook, which gets exactly the same stuff, you can reject the attempt to update the reference.  In a *post*-receive hook the update has already happened and the only thing you can do is report on it or make use of it somehow.)

In our case, we really don't care about the old value.  It doesn't matter if branch `master` never existed before, or what was deployed then.  (Well, we *might* want it, in which case we could add it: this is just a shell script, after all.)  We don't even really need the new value, because we can read that right out of the repository with a git command, but it's nice to have it, especially if we want to check and complain if the branch has been deleted.  (The branch is *probably* deleted if the attempt to read the `master` branch reference fails, but that could happen if the server has caught fire and the repository is half-destroyed, too.  Although in this case we might not care any more. :-) )

Mainly, though, what we need to do is check out all the files from branch `master`, sticking them into a deployment area.  As it turns out, we can do this with a simple `git checkout`, even in a bare repository, by specifying an alternate work-tree:

```
NULL_SHA1=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 # 40 0s

deploy() {
    local newref=$1 branch=$2

    if [ $newref = $NULL_SHA1 ]; then
        echo "deploy: branch $branch is deleted!"
        return 1
    fi
    # next bit is stupid, hardcodes "master" even though
    # we have "$branch", but read on...
    git --work-tree=/deploy/master checkout master
}
```

(Side note: sometimes you will see this as `GIT_WORK_TREE=/deploy/master git checkout master` or similar.  That does exactly the same thing.  If you don't specify `--work-tree` git uses `$GIT_WORK_TREE` if it's set.)

If we want more than just one (`master`) auto-deploy branch, we can add more branch names to the set that invoke `deploy` in our script, and fix the dumb bit: check out `$branch` to `/deploy/$branch`, for instance.

There are a number of potential glitches here though:

1. The target directory (here `/deploy/master`) must exist.
2. This kind of `git checkout` updates git's notion of "current branch".  A bare repository still has such a thing: there's still a file named `HEAD` that contains the current branch name.  If we `git checkout otherbranch` we'll change it; and this affects `git clone` operations that clone from this bare repository.
3. Git will make sure we don't clobber modified files.  Depending on the deployment directory and what gets done there, this may not be an issue.
4. Git likes to optimize checkouts.

Item 1 is easy enough to fix by first doing a `mkdir -p`.

Item 2 is not a problem if we only deploy `master`, or if we don't mind new clones potentially checking out branch `otherbranch` automatically.  But we can fix it by using a different form of `git checkout`.  We can add `-f` as well to fix item 3.

```
git --work-tree=/deploy/$branch checkout -f $branch -- .
```

This all introduces a new problem, though, which goes along with item 4.

Item 4 is the trickiest.  When you do a checkout *without* the `-- .` at the end, so that you're switching branches, git updates its index (staging area) file to keep track of what's already in the work tree.  Then when you do a new `git checkout` that replaces the previous one, it can tell which files can be left alone, which ones must be removed if any, and which ones must be rewritten or added.  Some deployment scripts (that check out one branch, like `master`) depend on this behavior.

If we switch the deployment code to use the `-- .` form, git *still* updates the index, but it won't *remove* files for us.  This means we need to clean out files that went away.  (It also winds up making a very messy index, but usually that's OK: this is a `--bare` repository that no one works in anyway.)

Cleaning out just the right files is tricky.  We can use the `$oldsha` method, comparing the old and new commits to determine what files to remove.  Or we can simply blow away the `/deploy/$branch` directory entirely:

```
rm -rf /deploy/$branch
mkdir /deploy/$branch
git --work-tree=/deploy/$branch checkout -f $branch -- .
```

This is often sufficient.  It still has a bug: there's a short period when the old deployed version is being removed, and the new deployed version is being built up, when things are a mess in the deploy directory.  But sometimes that's OK.

We can mostly-fix the bug by switching the order around: make a new empty directory, populate it, then `mv` the new directory into place (`mv`ing the old one out of the way) and only then `rm -rf` the (moved-out-of-the-way) old one.  There's still a tiny window during which the deploy directory does not exist, but it's as small as possible.  (Well, there's a potential to close it entirely with symlinks: see comments below.)

There's one last trick we can do, which I have never actually tested: we can get git to do most of the work, by using a different index file for each deploy directory.  Git uses `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`, if it's set, or `$GIT_DIR/index` if not.  So if we were to set `GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_DIR/index.$branch`, we should get a file unique to the particular branch name.  Then we can go back to the "check out a specific branch" form of `git checkout` and let it remove files if needed.

This last method opens the inconsistency window a bit wider: if git has to remove a dozen files and update or create another 100 files, whatever's using the deployed version has a lot more chances to see partial removes and/or updates as `git checkout` progresses.  But it is a lot simpler and has less "wasted motion" in the work tree.

#### One final ironic musing, as it were

Note that our `deploy` function sets up a work tree—or maybe one of several, if we have multiple deployable branches—as a literal git work tree, possibly even using `$GIT_WORK_TREE`.  It then clobbers whatever is in that work tree, replacing it with the latest version in the interesting branch.  This is exactly what we said would be annoying, back in the "background" section.  It's not annoying at all, it's just what we want!

Well, sort of.  The nice thing about this work tree, vs that bare repository, is that you cannot accidentally `cd /deploy/master`, see a `.git` directory, and start working in it.  There *is* no `.git` directory here.  Nonetheless, the combination of "work directory here" plus "bare repository there" really just equals "regular, non-bare repository", in almost every sense.

Comment: @derp: yes, I thought of that after writing up the answer, but decided not to add it: `ln -sf` is not necessarily atomic (it depends on whether `ln` implements it via a temp name and a `rename` system call, or does an `unlink` followed by a new `symlink`).  It's probably slightly faster, and possibly atomic, though, while the directory dance is definitely not atomic.

Comment: Wow. What an in depth answer! I'm going to have to read it a few times before it all sinks in lol. Currently my post receive hook is simply `git --work-tree=/path/to/folder --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git checkout -f` As you said, the remote is bare. One follow up: I don't always want to deploy certain branches to certain directories. Ex: doing updates for the holidays, so I push "holiday-promotions" branch to the live remote. Now the header & sidebar of a live site are all changed. Great! Jan 2 rolls around. A few changes on master, push master, site is now updated to post-holiday state.

Comment: In that case, it seems like a "situational map" (branch-name => target-directory based on additional information, such as "holiday coming") would be a reasonable approach.